# Stuck on blue screen saying error code 0xc0000225

Tags: bootcamp, imac

Reaching out for some help as I’m stuck on what to do.

I have an Intel iMac 2010 and recently the screen flashes black for little while then returns to normal. I hit the internet and see a website that describes the following for resetting the Nvram.

Step 2. Now start your iMac and then press command + option + P + R simultaneously on your keyboard. When you hear the open sound four times, you are allowed to release these options and your iMac screen will be normal.

So did this but now I get a blue error screen with the code 0xc0000225. Tried F8 and enter but it refreshes the screen then the Mac turns off!

I did have boot camp setup previously but thought I removed windows completely. My keyboard is wireless but tried the normal stuff like boot camp boot option key, resetting SMC.

At a complete loss. Hoping someone in the community has experience or a solution to the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What macOS, precisely? 2. The NVRAM reset wasn't going to fix anything, it almost never does, it's a bit of an interweb meme. 3. Macs never bluescreen, so you still have a [broken] Windows on there somewhere. 4. Try holding Opt at boot & tell us what you see [or photograph it] 5. Try Cmd/R at boot & see if you can get to Recovery.

Comment: Hi. 
It would have been High Sierra. The Blue screen is definitely a remnant from my old windows installation. Tried all the combination boot up keys but keeps coming to the same error screen. Can’t seem to get the Mac to recognise the Opt and boot etc. Seriously confusing and frustrating. 

I’m thinking only option is to extract HDD and put in a caddy and try and boot from another Mac.

Comment: I'd try to get it to boot from a High Sierra USB installer - that way you can get to Disk Utility & Terminal & see what's gone wrong with the drive structure.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Worth a try. I created a usb installer formatted to Mac using a Sierra DMG with transmac but after booting with Alt key no options just the same blue screen. Maybe the usb disk isn’t properly created but it’s a simple process. Seems the keys to get into boot options just aren’t recognised.

Comment: You're probably going to need a wired keyboard. Whether your USB is correctly set up or not, opt should do… something. If you only have a win keyboard, then ctrl & alt should behave as ctrl & opt, WInKey becomes Cmd. It doesn't work with all Win keyboards at boot, though they all should work once past there.